# App crashes in Android Studio using Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio

I have started from the very basic level in Android and have created a simple app to display Happy Birthday. But the App keeps crashing in both the Emulator and the Actual hardware(SAMSUNG NOTE 8).

Need help on how can i resolve the error.

**Here is xml Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/sample_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**MainActivity Code :**

```
 package com.example.android.happybirthday

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Example of a call to a native method
        sample_text.text = stringFromJNI()
      }

      /**
      * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
      * which is packaged with this application.
      */
     external fun stringFromJNI(): String

     companion object {

        // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
        init {
            System.loadLibrary("native-lib")
        }
      }
      }
```

Comment: Add your crash report

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: open your logcat and add your crash log

Comment: I am not seeing any error in the Logcat... Only in my device , the app show that "App has Stopped". Could you help me with collecting logs from the Emulator. Attaching the LOGCAT logs:

Comment: @Abhishekkumar, could you please guide me how i can get the crash report

Comment: Select logcat on Android studio select Error with select Show only selected Application.

Comment: then paste your activity class code also

Comment: U Meant the main_activity.xml code. if yes, it is pasted up. If not, how do i locate it

Comment: Add your MainActivity.java code @Virenmahajan here

Comment: Added the code above

Comment: I answered your Question , Please check @Virenmahajan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to typecast your `TextView` :

**Try with below code :**

```
  val sample_text  : TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text) as TextView
```

**Full Code :**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.TextView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val sample_text : TextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.sample_text) as TextView
        sample_text .text = "Happy Birthday"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome Happy to Help you, Accept my answer by tap on correct symbol at starting of my answer.